# AMD or Intel Versions of Ubuntu

Tags: versions

Part of the name of the ISO I downloaded was "amd64". Does that mean the ISO is only for AMD computers? Is there an Intel version?

Comment: `amd64` means that it is a 64-bit version.

Answer (score 2):

AMD64 is basically a synonym for [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64), x64, x86_64, and Intel 64. It is simply the the 64-bit version of the x86 instruction set.

The original specification was created by AMD and released in 2000, which is why people often use the AMD64 designation, as with the 64-bit ISO download of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

amd64 means it is for 64 bit processors. Its called so because amd invented this technology. The only reason why Intel also has this technology is because amd sold it to Intel. The other thing you found there should be called something with just x86 wich tells you that its 32 bit. But to be exact amd64 is x86_64, very simplified this is the reason you can run 32 bit programs on 64bit processors. If you have a very  small amount of RAM I would recommend the 32bit version, because it requires less. But I couldn't find exact numbers, think its about less than 2 gigabytes.